# create single field array from all the records

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to make array like this for the `Answer` field:

```
$my_array = array("Melon-Daiquiri.jpg1_2.jpg","banner1.png","images.jpg");
```

After that I want to use Shuffle function to show this record randomly.

Here is my `var_dump($array)` Output. (coming from database)

[image: Var_dump output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `array_map` like as its an array of objects you can simply achieve it like as

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { 
               return $v->Answer;
          },$your_array);
```

Comment: cool (Y) Now, can you tell me how can i loop this array with the other loop records. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, i am fetching all records using foreach loop. In which, i want to show all fields order by ID except Answer. So i want answer field should be randomly/shuffle visible to user. 

Example : if first record is visible to user then the answer field should be from different row. and If second record is visible to user then the Answer should comes from different row.

Comment: @kamaldeep Uchicha answered your question. If you have a new question, please post a new one and accept this answer.

Comment: @Uchiha, Resolved. :) Thanks alot for your help. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your are getting your data from database you can use `RAND()` mysql method to shuffle your data. example

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

Comment: we can randomly fetch the record using rand() function? 

Thanks for your help. :)